# what restrictions are applied on the use of prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql

i am using prepared statements in my project in php, on localhost it work fine but on server i t stops rendering page in the middle. i saw one error like this when i was executing nested queries on single statement and fixed that using 2 statements but this time i am executing 3 independent sql queries on single statement and still it stucks in last query...

all queries are independent i mean queries are not nested.

how should i fix it?

here is the last query

```
if($stmt->prepare("sql"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $material);
    $stmt->bind_result($mid, $subject, $title);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->fetch()){ // do something}
}
```

Comment: You should really post the queries.

Comment: what is ...prepare("sql") ..? I think there should a SQL-query instead of "sql"

Comment: @leeis, michi i removed query to save some space here is the query

Comment: 'select mid, subjects.subject, materials.title from materials, subjects where subjects.sid = materials.sid and materials.type = ? and materials.deleted='N' order by materials.title'

Comment: @peehaa error is simply page stops rendering before last query if i remove any one query it works fine... :(

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Have you setup PDO to throw exceptions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php and

Comment: @PeeHaa i turned on error reporting still that problem, isnt there PDO alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time i faced the same problem once again and solved it simple by executing my prepared statement first and then binding the result like:

```
if($stmt->prepare("sql query goes here"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $material);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($mid, $subject, $title);
    if($stmt->fetch()){ // do something}
}
```

hope this will help someone else too.